# Handling data in memory correctly in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, redis

I am working on an application that requires fast access to data that will change while the application is running.

It is an IRC bot for twitch.tv parsing hundreds of messages per second at peak times.

The data is saved in redis or mysql. Because sending a hget to redis everytime I need access to that data would be very inefficent I just save it in memory.

So on start of the application I load all data into memory from redis. so in an objet f.e. something like this:

channels[channel].config.response = 1

Which defines if the app should answer in chat.

This is really awkward because javascript is async and maybe channels[channel] is not defined because another function had to run first.

The challenge of this is dealing with multiple channels. I can't just save all my config in

```
var config = {};
```

So basicly what I am asking is if there is a better way of achieving what I want to achieve. 
Currently my code contains so many (typeof channels[channel] == 'undefined') it's getting annoying.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you actually determined by measuring that calling `hget()` is a bottleneck for your application? Redis is already an in-memory database ...

Comment: Not really.  But I can see the real life difference. Meaning it takes  few milliseconds to send an hget and that's time the bot doesn't answer to a command which is kinda annoying and in a fast chat with like 5 messages per second, it will be hard to read that answer.

Comment: Or another example I compare every word of every message against an array of words.  So that would send an hexists for every word in a message of a user.